# access violation error in deletion of nodes of a tree

Tags: c, tree

I am using the standard procedure to delete all nodes of tree, traversing post orderly and deleting the nodes.When I am using preorder traversal to display the empty tree, I am getting an access violation error, which I believe has to do with a null pointer.

```
void deleteallnodes(struct node **head){
    if(*head==NULL)
        return ;
    {
    deleteallnodes(&((*head)->left));
    deleteallnodes(&((*head)->right));
    free(*head);
    }
}
void main () {
    insert(&root,5);
    insert(&root,10);
    insert(&root,2);
    deleteallnodes(&root);
    preorder(root);
}
void preorder(struct node *root)
{
if (root)
{
    printf("\t %d",root->data);
    preorder(root->left);
    preorder(root->right);
}
}
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with your `deleteallnodes` function. Post the code for preorder; that is where you problem is

Answer (score 0):

you are not clearing the nodes when you delete them.  change the code to look like

```
free(*head);
*head = NULL;  // add this line
```

otherwise, in `preorder`, `if (root)` will succeed for deleted nodes and you will wander into memory that you do not control.

Comment: was this not correct?  feel free to say what didn't work (or mark as correct by clicking the "tick").